# Issue understanding static nested classes

Tags: java

Referencing the following example:

```
class Plane {
    ...
    static class Gearbox {
        ...
    }
}
```

The following is possible:

```
Plane.Gearbox gearbox = new Plane.Gearbox();
```

I was wondering if someone could explain what effect the 'static' keyword has in this situation. Coming from C#, this is very strange to me as static classes cannot be instantiated.

I am well aware that there are other questions referring to the same topic, or information online, however I still don't fully understand the use of the 'static' keyword in this situation. Therefore I would greatly appreciate someones help to understand this concept in Java.

Comment: Java `static` nested classes have absolutely nothing to do with how `static class` works in C#. See this official tutorial for an explanation of how they work in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html: **Note: A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.**  - A static nested class is just like a typical top level class.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, `static` means that an item is associated with the class itself and not with a specific instance of the class.